# Generics return type not working

Tags: java, generics, visitor-pattern

I'm going through example.

```
public interface Visitor<T> {
    public void visit(T e);
}

class Sum<T extends Integer> implements Visitor<T> {

    private int sum = 0;



    @Override
        public void visit(T element) {
            sum += element;
        }

        public T value() {
            return sum;
        }

}
```

The return statement T value() return sum is giving error stating that Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to T. Why it is so and how to fix the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `private T sum = 0;`?

Comment: Not all cats are lions, you know... ;-)

Comment: if T sum=0; I cannot add my element to the sum. I mean sum += element; in second method will give error.The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) T.

Comment: You cannot declare sum to be of type `T` and use `+=` because the `+` operator is only defined on primitive types (except `boolean`, obviously). It is not defined for objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case there are two problems:

1. `T extends Integer` is not exactly valid, because `Integer` cannot be extended, i.e. it's a  `final` class. Therefore you can safely change your class declaration to

   ```
   class Sum implements Visitor<Integer> { ...
   ```
2. Secondly, `T value()` method is not part of the interface and therefore does not need (should not) be of type `T`. You can safely replace it with `public int value()` or `public Integer value()`.

Therefore the resulting code will look like this:

```
class Sum implements Visitor<Integer> {
    private int sum = 0;

    @Override
    public void visit(Integer element) {
        sum += element.intValue();
    }

    public int value() {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `int` is a primitive type in Java, while `Integer` is a class. The problem is you cannot directly assign an `int` to an `Integer`. The solution may be to change `return sum;` into `return (T) sum;`.

Comment: return new T(sum) nor return new T(sum) is working giving Cannot instantiate the type T error.

Comment: public int value() {
  return sum;
 } worked thank you very much. But want to know T(sum)mean.

Comment: Considering `Integer` has a constructor as `Integer(int)`, I tried to express "create an new T instance from an int" with `new T(sum)` (assume `T` as `Integer` here will give you clearer impression). But then I found `Integer` is a final class which cannot be extended (or derived). Can I know what exactly is your `T` and `Integer` here? Are you referring to the default `Integer` in Java?

Comment: @grapeot Unlike C#, unfortunately you cannot do `new T()` in Java, because information about `T` type is now carried at runtime.

Comment: @rodion: I see. That's why @Eng.Fouad revised it as `(T) sum`. Sorry for writing the answer in the C# manner and thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: I'm refering to the default integer.

Comment: Then I totally agree with @rodion 's answer, you can safely substitute `T` with `Integer`. :)

Comment: @grapot you cannot cast to generic data type

Answer (score 1):

In Generics implementation always use `Wrapper` classes instead of `primitive` data types.
e.g. For `int` you should use `Integer` likewise for double,float,long etc. there are available wrapper classes are `Double, Float`and`Long` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the `intValue` method on class `Integer` (actually inherited from `Number`), i.e.

```
sum += element.intValue();
```

The reason why you cannot just use `sum += element` is that the compiler does not know what concrete class `T` is, so it cannot autobox. `T` *could* be `Integer`, but you've declared `T` to be `T extends Integer` so the compiler doesn't know what subclass `T` actually is.

Now, in your case it gets a little interesting because `Integer` is a final class. You could argue that the compiler should be able to figure out that `T` will always be `Integer`. It obviously doesn't do this.

Perhaps this is a case where you don't want to be using generics: there can never be a subclass of `Integer`, so why not get rid of the generic declaration altogether?

```
class Sum implements Visitor<Integer> {
    public void visit(Integer i) {
        sum += i;
    }
}
```

That should work just fine.